# Wordpress - have to press update on page to pull new plugin data

Tags: wordpress, updating

I'm using "Formidable Pro" which is a fairly popular plugin like Gravity forms. It has a portion to create forms and take those created entries and display them as "custom displays" which is working great EXCEPT for the fact that I have to go back to the page where the shortcode has been inserted to display these entries and hit update before it will pull the latest entries.

What in the world could be causing this?

I've already tried asking on their support forums and I'm getting no response so I'm kind of desperate. I've made sure that it is NOT the theme or other plugins causing the issue.

Issue lives on this page http://thenextarpg.com/skill-list/

Here where i have to hit update https://i.stack.imgur.com/iayzp.jpg

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably your caching plugin. Try disabling WP Super Cache and see if your problem goes away.

Assuming that is what's going on there may be some heavier development required to fix it.

I'd start by looking for a way to tell WP Super Cache never to cache that page.